# Regex expression that matches maximum of 2 asterisks and minimum of 2 chars other than asterisk

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to find the correct regular expression for matching those 2 conditions:

1. Must contain 1 or 2 `*` (2 maximum, but not necessarily consecutive)
2. Must contain at least two characters among digits and `.`

For exemple, following strings must match : `1*2`, `1**2`, `*2.*`.
Following strings must NOT match : `ab*`, `1*`, `1*2*.*`.

So far, I've tried the following regex for the two "parts", but without any success:

1. 1 or 2 `*`: `\*(?![\d.]*\*[\d.]*\*[\d.]*)`
2. At least two digits or `.`: `[\d.](?=[\*\d.]{2,})`

I'm struggling finding the correct regular expressions.

Comment: Which programming language/tool do you use?

Comment: I'm using Java (`Pattern.compile(...)`).

Comment: Does this have to be done with a single regular expression?  A solution would be dramatically easier to read and understand if it consisted of a few lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assert 2 times a dot or a digit, and then match 1 or 2 times an asterix:

```
^(?=(?:[^\d.\n]*[\d.]){2})(?:[^\n*]*\*){1,2}[^\n*]*$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=` positive lookahead, assert what to the right is

  - `(?:[^\d.\n]*[\d.]){2}` Match 2 times optional characters other than a digit, newline or dot, and then match a digit or dot
- `)` Close the lookahead
- `(?:[^\n*]*\*){1,2}` Repeat 1 or 2 times matching any character except a newline or `*`, and then match `*`
- `[^\n*]*` Match optional character except a newline or `*`
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PjYS6G/1)

Comment: Thanks @the-fourth-bird ! It seems to do the trick ! ;)